# Problem replicating IDENTITY columns from Sybase ASE 15.5 to Sybase ASE 15.5

Tags: replication, sybase, sybase-ase

I am trying to perform replication from `Sybase ASE 15.5` to `Sybase ASE 15.5` for a list of given tables via replication definitions and subscriptions defined in `Replication Server(REP) Version 15.7.1`. I found out that there is a table with one of the columns defined as `IDENTITY`. After creating the replication definition and subscription for that table, I am getting the below error messages in replication server:

Message from server: `Message: 584, State 1, Severity 16 -- 'Explicit value specified for identity field in table 'customers' when 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT' is OFF'.`

I have tried to run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON` on both of my primary and replicate database, but no luck.

Appreciate if you could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your primary/replicate tables were create like such:

```
create table mytable
(id     int           identity
,name   varchar(100)
,dob    date
... snip ...
```

And assuming you want to replicate identity values from the primary table to the replicate table, you need to tell SRS that the `id` column is an `identity` column, and the way you do this is by designating the `id` column as an `identity` in the repdef, like such:

```
create replication definition mytable_repdef
with primary at ...
with all tables named mytable
(id     identity             <<<=== use 'identity' instead of the actual datatype
,name   varchar(100)
,dob    datetime
... snip ...
```

By designating the `id` column as an `identity` column in the repdef, SRS should now enclose all INSERTs (sent to the replicate database) in a `set identity_insert on/off` wrapper, and UPDATEs should be wrapped in a `set identity_update on/off` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @markp. It works for ASE to ASE. Currently, I'm setting the same tables with same structure (with IDENTITY column) to Oracle (replicating from ASE to Oracle). I hit the SRS error 'ociStmt::Execute ORA-00922: missing or invalid option'. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I haven't tried replicating the ASE identity attribute to an Oracle sequence ... not even sure SRS can handle that; when the DSI goes down you can dump the problematic txn (`sysadmin dump_queue`) to see what command SRS is passing to Oracle, which I'm assuming is going to be an invalid command in Oracle ...

Comment: Thanks @markp. I have tried to dump_queue to check what command is running, but they are those common insert, update, delete statements, which should not cause the ORA-00922. I also see there are some command to insert value into INDENTITY value from ASE <ex. set identity_insert customer on insert into customer (id, customer_name) values (1, 'Jerry')set identity_insert customer off > Not sure if this command goes wrong in Oracle? Since the dump_queue from replication is only showing what transactions are executing in ASE, how am I suppose to check which command is invalid in Oracle?

Comment: The key is the part about `set identity_insert customer on insert ...` as that's part of the command ASE is sending to Oracle, and since `set identity_insert` is not a valid command in Oracle then that is likely the cause of the error the DSI is receiving.  If you're trying to replicate the same ASE table to both ASE and Oracle then you'll need to create 2x repdefs ... one for ASE w/ column defined as identity, one for Oracle w/ column defined as int... and it's important you create the ASE/identity repdef before you create the Oracle/numeric repdef; then you'll need 2 diff subs

Comment: Did you mean the structure to handle this IDENTITY column replication should be ASE1 --> ASE 2 (with column defined as identity), then from ASE1 --> Oracle (with column defined as int)? But how can I resolve my DSI error? I could not even drop the subscription/repdef of the particular table.

Comment: yes re: ASE/ASE/identity, ASE/ORA/int; as for the DSI issue ... hmmm ... what function string class do you have assigned to the Oracle DSI? now that I think about it, I'm surprised it would send 'set identity_insert' to oracle; as for the DSI (assuming correct funcstring class in place), depends on the volume of data in the queue and how easy/hard it will be to resync from ASE to ORA ... you could try `resume/skip tran` but that gets tedious if you have a lot of these; otherwise `'resume/skip to resync' is a quick-n-dirty way to clear the queue but it'll throw away *all* txns

Comment: once queue is clear ... `suspend` and (normal) `resume` will get DSI up again and allow you to drop/recreate the repdef/sub, but you'll need to go through a resync method

Comment: I have recreated a new repdef with ASE-ORA (with column defined as int). When I tried to resume connection, it showing me error ORA-00942 table or view does not exist. Further check on the dump queue, I still found there is <set identity_insert dbo.repdef_customer on insert into dbo.repdef_customer (, ,) values (1, 'Jerry')set identity_insert dbo.repdef_customer off>. It is weird because it specific the tablename to be dbo.repdef_customer, which repdef_customer is referring to my repdef name. Do you have any idea?

Comment: you probably marked the table with `owner on` and/or explicitly listed the owner in the repdef; you should be able to get around this by providing both primary and replicate owner.table names in the repdef

Comment: Hi @markp, actually I will be doing replication from ASE-ASE-Oracle. For ASE-ASE replication, I am replicating 2 same tables but in the different data server (ex. customer in ASE1; and customer in ASE2). In the repdef level of this 2 ASE-ASE replication, I have defined the identity column as 'identity' datatype. For ASE-Oracle replication, am I suppose to replicate the customer table in ASE1 or ASE2 to Oracle?

Comment: That's your call. I'd probably rep straight from ASE1 to Oracle instead of having to deal with replicating into and then out of ASE2 (doable but a tad bit more complicated).

Comment: Tried to setup replication from ASE1 to Oracle and hit the error `The datatype of column 'id' was specified by other replication definitions as an IDENTITY column.` Seems we cannot have 2x repdef, which one defined with identity column and another one defined with numeric in the repdef?

Comment: Hi @markp, is there any other alternatives could try?

Comment: multiple repdefs are allowed; hard to say without diving into a lot more detail ... definitely more than can be handled in back-n-forth comment blocks; start from scratch ... drop all subs/repdefs for table, create identity repdef, create int repdef, create subs

Comment: Recreated all over again, ASE1 replicate to ASE2 using 'identity' as datatype in repdef; ASE1 replicate to Oracle using 'int' as datatype in repdef, still I'm getting the same error `The datatype of column 'id' was specified by other replication definitions as an IDENTITY column.` This is ridiculous..

Comment: Further checked from other sites, Found that `Different replication definitions created for the same primary table must use the same declared column datatype`.

Comment: how did you mark the primary database ... sp_reptostandby, sp_setreptable?  if sp_reptostandby, also try sp_setreptable

Comment: I marked my primary database using sp_setreptable

Comment: I don't have an ASE-Oracle setup in front of me; for ASE-ASE setups I've used dual repdefs to route identity to one db, and numeric to another db; the last idea I have (off the top of my head) is to define the column as `numeric` (as opposed to `int`) in the 2nd repdef (though I'd expect `int` to work)

Comment: Have tried to define as `numeric` in my ASE-ORA repdef, its not working too.

Comment: I have tried to setup the same dual repdef to route identity to one table, and numeric to another table under the same database. It's not working too, I'm still getting `The datatype of column 'id' was specified by other replication definitions as an IDENTITY column.`

Comment: one more idea, on the 2nd repdef: `<column> identity map to int`

Comment: Replication is working fine right now! I used `<column> identity map to numeric` instead! Thanks a lot @markp !!!